# Share Image on Facebook when there isn't installed facebook app

Tags: android, facebook-share

I want to share image from external storage on facebook in cases when user don't have facebook app installed on his/her phone. I tried to open ShareDialog, but in it doesn't run correct, I am getting error

**facebook don't allow to share image Unable to show the provided content via the web or the installed version of the Facebook app. Some dialogs are only supported starting API 14**

I want to mention that API is higher 14.

Here is my ShareDiaolog code.

```
   enter code here

package com.palabs.polygon.activities;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.share.ShareApi;
import com.facebook.share.Sharer;
import com.facebook.share.model.ShareLinkContent;
import com.facebook.share.model.ShareOpenGraphAction;
import com.facebook.share.model.ShareOpenGraphContent;
import com.facebook.share.model.ShareOpenGraphObject;
import com.facebook.share.model.SharePhoto;
import com.facebook.share.model.SharePhotoContent;
import com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog;
import com.palabs.polygon.R;

import java.io.File;

public class FacebookImageShare extends AppCompatActivity {

    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    ShareDialog shareDialog;
    String path;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        Intent i=getIntent();
        path=i.getStringExtra("ImagePath");
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        // this part is optional
        shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                Log.e("xxx", "onsuccess" + result.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.e("xxx", "oncancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.e("xxx", "onerror" + error);
            }
        });


        if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
            SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                    .setBitmap(bitmap)
                    .setCaption("Effect")
                    .build();

            SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                    .addPhoto(photo)
                    .build();

            shareDialog.show(content);
        }

    }

    public static Uri getImageContentUri(Context context, String filePath) {
       // String filePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID },
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=? ",
                new String[] { filePath }, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
            cursor.close();
            return Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + id);
        } else {

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filePath);
                return context.getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try this http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-share-an-image-on-facebook-in-android/ although I am not exactly sure if it will help you!

Comment: I tried that code too, but it did not help. Thank you.